# Horizontal scroll in css

Tags: html, css, scroll

I know there is some topics about this on the web but I'm searching for like an hour and still can't find a solution for my problem.

I want to make a simple horizontal scroll like I can see all over the web but I have some troubles for doing it.

Here is my code :

The HTML part :

```
<div class="cards scrolling-wrapper">
      <div class="card-wrapper">
          <h4>Adresse</h4>
          <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
          <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper">
          <h4>Adresse</h4>
          <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
          <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper">
          <h4>Adresse</h4>
          <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
          <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
</div>
<div class="card-wrapper">
          <h4>Adresse</h4>
          <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
          <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Don't matter about the {{ shop.name }} and {{ shop.address }}, I'm using Angular.

Here is my CSS code :

```
.scrolling-wrapper{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.card-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  width: calc(100vw - 50px);
  padding: 25px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;

h4 {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h5 {
  color: $darker-grey;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  white-space: normal;
}
}
```

With this my cards are showed inline, but I can't scroll at all.
If I remove the `white-space: normal;` from the `p` I can scroll a little, like one card and a half but can't go further.

How can I fix that ?

**EDIT :**

I manage to get it 'works', an `overflow: hidden` in a parent element was blocking my scroll.

But now I have another problem, I can scroll inside my `scrolling-wrapper` but it scroll also the background (which is a map), so when I start to scroll inside my `scrolling-wrapper` the map go on the left and I have a blank background.

Is there a way to avoid this ? And just scroll the cards, not the entiere page.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqbjNP it seems scrollable

Comment: That's weird I can't scroll at all on my app but in the codepen I can

Comment: Firstly your css code formatting is not propper   in your css    ".card-wrapper"  css is not closed "}" sign missing..    add this firstly... and here is your scroll is working..

Comment: For the close sign it's normal i'm using scss, but I still can't make it work on my app, and I don't uderstand why

Comment: I think check body css.. may be there is extra css for overflow: hidden;   check this.

Comment: Is it a particular browser related issue? I copied your code into an html and css file (changed closing bracket for css) and i had horizontal scrolling in chromium.

Comment: I found my problem but another appeared, can you look at my edit please ?

Comment: @Jess can you make a small demo over codepen ?

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwBXNB    the grey background is my map, and when I scroll the cards the background is scrolling too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max-width: 100vw; padding: 20px 0; margin:0;` property on your `.scrolling-wrapper`.
And give

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.map{
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
}

.scrolling-wrapper{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      max-width: 100vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: tomato;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.card-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  width: calc(100vw - 50px);
  padding: 25px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;

h4 {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h5 {
  color: $darker-grey;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="map-wrapper">
      <div class="map">
        
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="cards scrolling-wrapper">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
              <h4>Adresse</h4>
              <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
              <p class="address">{{ shop.address }}</p>
              <p *ngIf="shop.phone != null" class="tel">Tel : {{ shop.phone }}</p>
          </div>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
              <h4>Adresse</h4>
              <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
              <p class="address">{{ shop.address }}</p>
              <p *ngIf="shop.phone != null" class="tel">Tel : {{ shop.phone }}</p>
          </div>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
              <h4>Adresse</h4>
              <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
              <p class="address">{{ shop.address }}</p>
              <p *ngIf="shop.phone != null" class="tel">Tel : {{ shop.phone }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Jess also upvote the solution, it helps the new users looking for the answers.

Comment: I know but I can't :/ I don't have 15 reps ^^'

Answer (score 0):

just give overflow: auto to the parent container like that:

```css
.scrolling-wrapper{
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scrolling-wrapper .card-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
      <h4>Adresse</h4>
      <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
      <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <h4>Adresse</h4>
    <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found my problem (just a css thing) but another appeared, can you look at my edit please ?